# Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.. failed

Tags: web-services, security

I am getting this error when calling a web service method which writes to a file on the local drive on Windows 2003.

"System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed."

I have done these steps:

- website runs in an appPool using the localSystem identity
- website impersonates a user in the admin group.
- the web service assembly has full trust
- the url of the web service has full trust in the machine's web.config.
- the folder's written to security has the impersonated user

So why is this web service still complaining about FileIOPermission? Fulltrust includes FileIOPermission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of troubleshooting, it boiled down to a mistake I made in web.config where the location tag had a path of www.example.com but in IIS it was example.com!

Answer (score 2):

Right click on Project-> Properties -> Security Tab -> Enable Click Once Settings

Click on 'Calculate Permissions'.

Click 'Yes' on 'Full Trust Required' message.

Then the issue was solved.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally we have found the issue. After building the files in Windows we put them in a zip file. When the files are added to the zip windows adds a blocking property to all files which remains after unzipping the folder. These caused the files to not be able to run properly. The "block" property can be removed by right-clicking on the files (one at the time), select "Properties" and then clicking the "Unblock" button at the bottom. Here is an example picture:

https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/image10.png

To prevent windows from adding this blocking property, one can look at the following thread:

[Can I stop windows from “Blocking” zip files](https://superuser.com/questions/302146/can-i-stop-windows-from-blocking-zip-files)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's no longer relevant, but I solved like this:

```
Project > Properties > Security > Enable ClickOnce security settings - Uncheck
```

[image]